# How to expose wordpress over hostname in kubernetes

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

I deploy a kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu following the steps described at [this link](https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-with-kubeadm/)

Then I deploy a Wordpress following steps found at [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)

Everything works fine but I miss what I should do to serve the wp instance at a specific hostname like `http://wp.example.com` instead of `http://[kubeip]:port`

I'd like to have several different WP instances which respond to specific url.
I tried to have a look at Ingress but I did not find nothing clear and I don't know if it's the right choice.

Can someone suggest me something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an ingress controller.

You could go with the nginx-ingress-controller, traefik, haproxy, ... several implementations exist.

Then, in addition to creating a Service exposing your wordpress container, you would create an Ingress object.

Answer (score 1):

TY. I follow the guide to add the nginx-ingress-controller in a bare-metal at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps

Then I tried to use a ingress.yaml like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: wordpress-ingress
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
    defaultBackend:
        service:
            name: wordpress
            port:
                number: 80
    rules:
      - host: wp.example.com
        http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                    service:
                        name: wordpress
                        port:
                            number: 80
```

But it doesn't work as expected

Comment: try to remove the rewrite-target annotations. The `spec.defaultBackend` section should not be necessary. The rest looks OK (for http/port 80). For https, you would have to add some `spec.tls` configuration, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls

Comment: Also, the instructions you followed did create a NodePort service, exposting nginx: this is not what you want. You want to use hostNetwork, exposing your nodes ports 80/443 directly. See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network . (if RBAC enabled, would requires host access privileges, for the ServiceAccount that runs your Nginx controller)

Comment: Ok! I'll try with the hostNetwork configuration for nginx-ingress-controller

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use Helm to install your wordpress with this command

```
helm upgrade --install picvec-wp bitnami/wordpress --set global.storageClass=nfs-client --set ingress.enabled=true --set ingress.hostname=wp.novinparva.com --set ingress.path=/ --set ingress.tls=true --set ingress.extraHosts[0].name=wp.novinparva.com --set ingress.extraHosts[0].path=/ --set ingress.certManager=true --set wordpressPassword=asdvqwkjn --set mariadb.auth.rootPassword=$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD --set mariadb.auth.password=$MARIADB_PASSWORD  --set allowOverrideNone=false --set htaccessPersistenceEnabled=true
```

Comment: Cluster doesn't have an ingress controller. Also, I wouldn't recommend bitnami images in general. Especially when editor publishes official images: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress

Comment: you can use nginx to set proxy to your specefic port
server {


 server_name wp.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://[kubeip]:port;
  include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }
}

Comment: Then this should be your answer. Not installing random helm charts. Though the way it was formulated, I don't think op wants to install another server alongside Kubernetes, rather to get Kubernetes doing that port translation.